# Appcenter is not showing all application on repos

Tags: appcenter, apt, elementary-project

I have installed 6.1 version.I realised that a lot of apps in repos not showing on appcenter.

I have updated via apt but this issue is keeping on.

Answer (score 0):

Install an application from flathub and then open the appcenter, the flatpak flathub applications should appear.